# Jenkins and Nexus Repository Manager Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, sonatype

I know there is a Nexus Platform plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-jenkins-plugin/ in Jenkins but I am not sure if the below is possible any advise or suggestions would be appreciated.

In Jenkins you have Git choice parameter this allows you to build specific tags / branches within your job is there something similar for Sonatype Nexus? We have an internal nexus where we upload and tag docker images.

I currently have a Jenkins job I have to manually type in the image version.
Is there a way in Jenkins to get a choice parameter where i can query all the tags in nexus.

So for example I can run the command - > docker pull internal/application/service:0.0.1
So the developers would upload a new version for example 0.0.2

From Jenkins I would like to display a list of 0.0.1 or 0.0.2 for the support team to build.
Not sure if this is currently possible ?

Update 2020/07/15

I have read up on the active choice paramater plugin. This allows you to execute a groovy script.

So i created the below

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// GET
try {
    def get = new URL("http://internalserver:8081/service/rest/v1/search?repository=docker-internal&name=application/service/moo").openConnection();
    def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
//println(getRC);
    if (getRC.equals(200)) {
        //println(get.getInputStream().getText());
        JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
        Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(get.getInputStream().getText())
        tags = parsedJson.items.version
        //println(tags)
        def sorted_tags = []
        sorted_tags.push(tags)
        println(sorted_tags)
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    println(e)
}
```

This code does print out the tags if i run it from my IDE but if i add it to the active choice plugin my drop down menu is blank ?

Comment: Please reword questiin ... There is no "Nexus repository manager in Jenkins". There are plugin [Nexus Platform](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-jenkins-plugin), [Nexus Artifact uploader](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-artifact-uploader/) and of possible interest [Maven Artifact ChoiceListProvider (Nexus)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-artifact-choicelistprovider/).. but all tie in to standalone Nexus.

Comment: sorry meant to say nexus platform plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it to work Jenkins combo box requires a return type.
So if anyone ever wants to do something similar the below worked for me.

```
<code>
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
try {
    def get = new URL("http://yourinternalnexusurl:8018/applicacation/v1...etc").openConnection();
    def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
    if (getRC.equals(200)) {
        def nexus_response = [:]
        nexus_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(get.getInputStream().getText())
        def image_tag_list = []
        for (tag in nexus_response.items.version){
            image_tag_list.add(tag)
        }
       return image_tag_list.sort()
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    println(e)
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Artifact ChoiceListProvider (Nexus)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-artifact-choicelistprovider) may satisfy your requirements.

> With this extension its possible to use the Service API from a Maven Repositories like Nexus, Maven-Central or Artifactory to search for artifacts using groupId, artifactId and packaging.

> This plugin will let the user choose a version from the available artifacts in the repository and will publish the URL as an environment variable. The Plugin will return the full URL of the choosen artifact, so that it will be available during the build, i.E. you can retrieve the artifact by using "wget"
> Example

You might then have to parse (groovy ?)  the resulting env variable to feed as your parameter.

Comment: I will have a look, but i think thats just for artifacts and not tags but will see what I can do thank you very much for the suggestion

Comment: Perhaps you can submit an [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20maven-artifact-choicelistprovider-plugin) to extend the plugin or contribute to it and [submit a PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-artifact-choicelistprovider-plugin/pulls) ?